# Omit certain columns when comparing two Excel files, using SAS code

Tags: sas

Could someone please help me with adding to the code below. I am trying to compare to similar Excel files. 
I do not want columns with the word in the column ‘Area’ to be compared.
Example of a column heading  ‘Building_Area_Site‘
Many thanks in advance.

```
PROC COMPARE BASE=WORK.DATA_201607 COMPARE=WORK.DATA_201608 out=dif outbase outcomp outnoequal listall OUTDIF METHOD=PERCENT CRITERION=10.00 maxprint=(1000);
   ID NAME_id;
   run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify what columns to exclude, but you can list vars to include on the VAR statement.

Query the sasahelp.vcolumn table to get only columns of interest and pass those to the VAR statement.

```
proc sql noprint;
select name into :var_list separated by " "
from sashelp.vcolumn
 where libname="WORK" and memname='RAW_DATA' and       upcase(name) not like '%AREA%'
order by varnum;
quit;
```

Then add the VAR statement to your proc compare code.

```
VAR &var_list;
```